# Statistical test of two groups of frequencies

Tags: inference, frequency

I have two groups of frequency data with different sample sizes and want to perform a statistical test on them. Given that the origin is count data is a non parametric test such as `Mann–Whitney U test` appropriate, or would a `T-test` or some other frequency specific test be more appropriate here?

```
Mann–Whitney U test result: statistic=161.0, pvalue=0.00045559069195569816
T-test result statistic=3.4450111759267736, pvalue=0.0008550201339166953
```

Group one:

```
       2.88736949e-05, 1.91629064e-04, 8.33259266e-05, 1.25364623e-03,
       5.49663735e-04, 7.36399464e-05, 5.30926467e-04, 1.15539006e-04,
       4.61161792e-04, 2.55944013e-04
```

Group two:

```
       1.09393232e-05, 1.59506593e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 3.39931153e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 7.47160789e-06, 9.14335754e-04,
       6.37270854e-04, 4.38065997e-04, 4.46014156e-04, 4.33364272e-04,
       4.27734969e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.15975733e-06, 2.35208535e-04,
       2.16038714e-05, 1.51515152e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       4.52923797e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.94096488e-04,
       1.62733510e-04, 5.32050736e-05, 1.66583845e-04, 1.59014260e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.56678730e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 3.11371279e-05,
       1.75217269e-05, 9.45332757e-05, 2.69473987e-05, 4.04825815e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 3.45638048e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 3.87837419e-06,
       0.00000000e+00, 4.67709347e-06, 2.42479972e-04, 3.46202847e-06,
       4.12178501e-04, 4.24117093e-04, 1.78833810e-04, 3.35415084e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 3.27687776e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.88196326e-05, 1.68599946e-05,
       7.08616780e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 1.45213755e-05, 1.87207111e-04,
       3.61039795e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.34105783e-05,
       0.00000000e+00, 5.01465823e-04, 9.99428898e-05, 2.88406076e-04,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       2.94117647e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.29346026e-05, 2.29624640e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00
```

Comment: Are the original count data available or only the fractions?

Comment: @Bernhard The original counts are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably not one true way to approach this. You can certainly approach these data as numerical values that are left-censored and therefore highly non-normal. You can choose to test these with a rank sum / U test which will yield a significant $p$ value (I get a differnt result somewhere along the lines of `.0003` but yours is even smaller - maybe you presented only part of the data).

By choosing the nonparametric test you will not have to discuss whether you should have used an arcsine transform or a logit transform and whether the numbers are high enough to do a t-test in absence of normality.

Comment: Very good point, I don't think the sample size for group one is large enough to do a t-test in absence of normality. Sticking with the nonparametric seems the easy route for me then!

All the data is presented so that is odd you get a smaller p-value. What language and package did you use for the test?

Comment: "easy" means "pragmatic", as long as your not cheating. I do not regard this as cheating in any way.